# ¿Como cargar datos obtenidos de un Ajax en el atributo "description" en Openlayers 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, openlayers

es la primera vez que eso la API de OSM con OpenLayers y tengo el problema que al querer cargar los valores devueltos con un Ajax, no me los carga. esto sucede en el atributo de *"description"* de la funcion **new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector**, esto es para marcadores dinámicos. Les dejo el codigo que tengo, si alguien tiene alguna idea o haya trabajado con esta API y tenga mas experiencia, se los agradeceria mucho.

Este es mi codigo:

```js
function initOpenStreetMap() {

  epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection
  projectTo = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); //The map projection (Spherical Mercator)

  /* div content map and controls of map */
  map = new OpenLayers.Map("map_canvas", {
    controls: [
      new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(), // Navegar por el mapa.
      //new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),                             // La escala utilizada en el mapa.
      new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(), // Mover el mapa con el teclado.
      new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom()
    ]
  });
  map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

  var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('StreetMap', {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
      externalGraphic: 'img/icon-hotel.png',
      graphicWidth: 32,
      graphicHeight: 46,
      graphicYOffset: -24
    })
  });


  var feature = [];
  if (locations.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      var datainfo = $('#search_params').val();
      datainfo += '/byuid/' + locations[i][1];

      var LonLati = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(locations[i][3], locations[i][2]).transform(epsg4326, projectTo);
      var feature2 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(LonLati);
      feature.push(feature2);
      feature2.attributes.description = '<h3>' + locations[i][0] + '</h3><br><a href="' + datainfo + '"> Mas Informacion</a><div id="info_show"></div>';

      $(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'html',
          url: datainfo,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#info_show').append('"' + data + '"');
            //description: data
          }
        });

      })



      /*map.events.register("click", map , function(event){
       //createInfo(map, event.LonLati, datainfo);
      });*/

    }
  }

  vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
  map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

  //Add a selector control to the vectorLayer with popup functions
  var controls = {
    selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
      onSelect: createPopup,
      onUnselect: destroyPopup
    })
  };

  function createPopup(feature) {
    feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
      feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
      null,
      '<div class="markerContent">' + feature.attributes.description + '</div>',
      null,
      true,
      function() {
        controls['selector'].unselectAll();
      }
    );
    map.addPopup(feature.popup);
  }

  function destroyPopup(feature) {
    feature.popup.destroy();
    feature.popup = null;
  }

  map.addControl(controls['selector']);
  controls['selector'].activate();

  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(locations[0][3], locations[0][2]).transform(epsg4326, projectTo), 12);
}
```

Los datos que se obtienen, vienen de un arreglo, *locations[i][1]* es un token o funciona como identificador, estoy intentando ejecucar el ajax y cargar lo que regresa, pero no esta funcionando. Intente con la función de map.events.register pero no hubo resultados.

saludos y agradeceria el apoyo, aportes e ideas.